# Parse header to unordered list IN PLAIN JS

Tags: javascript, dom

A part of my script

```
function lab()
{
var h1 = getElementsByTagName("H1");
var li = document.createElement("LI");
var ul = document.createElement("UL");
li.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML;
h1[0].parentNode.replaceChild(ul,h1[0]);
h1[0].parentNode.appendChild(li);
}
```

doesn't do anything.

The whole task is to change a combination of headers to unordered list using only plain js with DOM. There has already been a question here but unfortunately the solution provided there was in jQuery, not in plain JS.

Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you need, perhaps something like this:

```
function lab() {
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1'), // Create a collection of H1 elements
        ul = document.createElement('ul'),        // Create a new UL element
        parent = h1[0].parentNode,                // Store the parent node of the first H1
        n, len, li;                               // Declare some variables to use later
    for (n = 0, len = h1.length; n < len; n++) {  // Iterate through H1 elements
        li = document.createElement('li');        // Create a new LI element
        li.appendChild(h1[0]);                    // Move a H1 to LI (Live collection, 0 instead of n as index)
        // Or switch the line above to the next two lines, if you want to remove the H1 and list the content only
        // li.innerHTML = h1[0].innerHTML;
        // h1[0].parentElement.removeChild(h1[0]);// If you want to preserve H1s, remove this line
        ul.appendChild(li);                       // Append the newly-created LI to the UL
    }
    parent.appendChild(ul);                       // Append the UL to the parent
}
```

This collects all `H1` elements to an unordered list, which is appended to the parent element of the first `H1`.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2W4h8/).